# How do I manage my cat food in the absence of maid?

Tags: pets

I have a cat at home. My maid is on leave for a week and am not available at home from 9am to 5pm(everyday). How do I manage the cats lunch? If I serve the lunch in the morning(before leaving home) it will eat up before afternoon.It gets even more difficult when am out for more then a day on business trip. What do I do?

Comment: Why feed the cat lunch at all?  My cats were quite healthy being fed twice a day.

Answer (score 4):

If the cat's over six months old, it doesn't need lunch - in fact, once a day is quite adequate, but put food down in the morning and more when you get home. For if you're away for longer than a day, you'll need a timed cat feeder as mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: The OP doesn't specify how the cats are being fed; they are evolved for multiple small meals through the day, so if the food can't be left out (dry kibble), they need 3+ meals per day.

Comment: @AllisonC Not so, see here https://www.vet.cornell.edu/departments-centers-and-institutes/cornell-feline-health-center/health-information/feline-health-topics/how-often-should-you-feed-your-cat

Comment: that doesn't disagree with what I said. They're advocating dry kibble (which is falling out of vogue with vets), which, as I said, can be left out for them to graze at (thereby providing their own 3+ meals per day).

Comment: See also https://pets.webmd.com/cats/guide/mistakes-people-make-feeding-cats#2 (wet vs dry), https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/feeding-times-and-frequency-for-cats (minimum 2 feedings), https://pets.webmd.com/cats/guide/feeding-your-adult-cat-what-you-need-to-know#3 (minimum 2 feedings), https://www.petmd.com/cat/nutrition/how-calculate-how-much-wet-food-feed-cat (minimum 2 feedings)

Comment: @AllisonC 'vogue' being the appropriate word here - cats are, first and foremost, animals. I''ve had a total of 9 cats over the years, 6 of those raised from kittens. All were given dry food to snack on whenever they felt like it, and one 'wet' meal a day. All lived healthy, active, long lives (around 18 and a half years) bar one, which had  a congenital heart defect. They did, though, have full access to outdoors whenever they wanted, and were expected to catch vermin - not that they all did, only two were good mousers. But they were also pets as well as animals, and I miss 'em all... .

Comment: Yes, "vogue," because professionals are realizing that the previously presumed "benefits" of dry food aren't really there, it's just a convenience to humans. I've had more cats than I can count over the years, all of them raised from kittens. Yes, plenty did fine on dry food, but the ones I've given only 'wet' thrive far more than the ones on dry ever did.

Comment: @AllisonC Please take discussions to the [chat]

Answer (score 2):

Use a Pet Feeder and if you're creative : make it yourself with the help of a Raspberry Pi

[RPi Pet Feeder](http://drstrangelove.net/2013/12/raspberry-pi-power-cat-feeder-updates/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to spend quite a bit, there're a few timed pet feeders I saw on Amazon. Here's the one I liked the most :)

[Timed pet feeder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0111U10GA)

Answer (score 0):

I put down food for my cat in the morning and he decides as and when he eats. You don't need to specifically feed a cat at a time.

Once a day is adequate.

Comment: Only if feeding something that can be left out (dry kibble). Cats who are fed other meals (wet/canned, raw) need to be fed 3+ times per day. The asker did not specify how their cats are fed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to contact and trust one of your neighbours to feed the cat unless you can't take a break and come from work to do it.

Comment: Please no. Neighbors are not an option. Any better suggestions please.

Comment: any friend or family available?